# Default Mime type in Rails 5 controller tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I know that starting with Rails 5.0 I can add `as: :json` attribute to send the test HTTP request with `application/json` content type like this:

```
post :create, params: { account_id: 123, user: { ... } }, as: :json
```

Is there a way to configure this behavior globally, so that I don't need to specify the content type on each test?

I'm upgrading from Rails 4.2 and realised that without this attribute all my requests are treated as URL encoded forms, including my payload being URL encoded. This is causing many failures when I run my test suite and for some reason was working just fine in Rails 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just override `ActionDispatch::Integration::RequestHelpers#process`.

```
module JSONRequestHelper
  alias_method :original_process, :process
  def process(method, path, **args)
    original_process(method, path, args.merge(as: :json))
  end
end
```

---

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApiTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include JSONRequestHelper
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify in your routes the default format for them, like so:

```
defaults format: :json do
  resources :photos
end
```

as can be seen here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults

You can always use a before_action as well:

```
before_action :set_format

def set_format
  request.format = 'json'
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems this way I can only instruct rails about the format in which it should return the response. My problem is that minitest encodes my request payload as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and it's not only about the header but also it does actually encode the 'user' value as URL encoded string. Setting the default format: :json on route level didn't help, only using as: :json on test did help.